# задача на поиск в ширину "витрина"

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Не могу решить задачу на поиск в ширину.
Витрина

ссылка на задачу  https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?chapterid=608#1

Зал супермаркета имеет форму прямоугольника размером
M
x
N
, в котором расставлены витрины размером 1 x 1. Стороны витрин параллельны стенам супермаркета, а расстояния от витрин до стен – целые числа.

В супермаркет привезли новую супервитрину размером
K
x 1 и выгрузили в одном из углов супермаркета. Требуется передвинуть ее в противоположный угол супермаркета. При этом ее нельзя поворачивать, а можно лишь передвигать параллельно стенам супермаркета. Напишите программу, которая по плану супермаркета поможет определить, какое наименьшее количество витрин нужно убрать, чтобы передвинуть супервитрину.

Входные данные
В первой строке вводятся три натуральных числа
M
,
N
и
K
(
M
,
N
≤ 100,
K
≤
M
). Начальное и конечное расположение супервитрины такие, как указано на верхнем рисунке. В следующей строке записано целое неотрицательно число
V
– количество витрин (0 ≤
V
≤
N
*
M
). В следующих
V
строках входных данных содержатся различные пары целых неотрицательных чисел, характеризующие положения витрин. Первое число (от 0 до
M
–1) – расстояние от левой стены супермаркета до витрины, второе (от 0 до
N
–1) – расстояние от нижней стены до витрины (см. нижний рисунок). Гарантируется, что там, где изначально поставили супервитрину, других витрин нет.

Выходные данные
В первой строке выведите минимальное количество витрин, которые необходимо убрать. Во второй строке выведите возможный маршрут передвижения супервитрины: одну строку из заглавных латинских букв, обозначающих следующее:

U – на 1 вверх,
D – на 1 вниз,
L – на 1 влево,
R – на 1 вправо.
Количество символов в строке не должно превышать
N
x
M
.

Если возможных маршрутов несколько, то выведите любой из них.

Примеры

Входные данные

```
9 3 2
4
2 0
5 1
5 2
8 2
```

Выходные данные

```
1
URRRDRRRRUU
```

Я решал так: В двумерный массив храню были ли мы в этой точки или нет, а если были то храню в нём кол-во витрин которые надо убрать и длину пути. При поиске смотрел в четыре стороны были ли мы в этой клетке или нет, а если были, то сравниваю текущее кол-во витрин, которые нужно убрать чтобы перейти на эту клетку и кол-во витрин, которые в той клетки уже есть и брал минимальную. Если они оба одинаковые то брал минимальную длину пути.

Только первые пять тестов проходятся. Код большой получился. Я не до конца уверен что мой алгоритм правильный. Скажите где ошибка в коде или правильный алгоритм. Я буду очень благодарен.

тестил час и не нашёл ошибку

Не ругайте плз(( я новичок((

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
vector<vector<bool>>a(104,vector<bool>(104,false));
vector<vector<pair<int,int>>>b(104,vector<pair<int,int>>(104,{-1,-1}));
queue<pair<int,int>>q;
int n,m,r;
int main(){
    int k;
    cin>>m>>n>>r>>k;
    while(k){
        int t1,t2;
        cin>>t1>>t2;
        t1++;
        a[n-t2][t1]=1;
        k--;
    }
    b[n][r].first=0; // витрины которые нужно убрать
    b[n][r].second=0; // длина пути
    q.push({n,r});
    while(q.size()){
        int x = q.front().first,y = q.front().second;
        q.pop();
        if(x>1 && y >=r){
            int k =0; // кол-во витрин сверху
            for(int t = y-r+1;t<=y;t++){
                k+=a[x-1][t];
            }
            if(b[x][y].first+k<b[x-1][y].first || (b[x][y].first+k==b[x-1][y].first && b[x][y].second+1<b[x-1][y].second) || b[x-1][y].first==-1){
                b[x-1][y].first=b[x][y].first+k;
                b[x-1][y].second=b[x][y].second+1;
                q.push({x-1,y});
            }
        }
        if(y<m && (a[x][y+1]+b[x][y].first < b[x][y+1].first ||(a[x][y+1]+b[x][y].first == b[x][y+1].first && b[x][y].second+1 < b[x][y+1].second) || b[x][y+1].first==-1)){
            q.push({x,y+1});
            b[x][y+1].first=b[x][y].first+a[x][y+1];
            b[x][y+1].second=b[x][y].second+1;
        }
        if(y>1 && (a[x][y-1]+b[x][y].first < b[x][y-1].first||(a[x][y-1]+b[x][y].first == b[x][y-1].first && b[x][y].second+1 < b[x][y-1].second)|| b[x][y-1].first==-1)){
            q.push({x,y-1});
            b[x][y-1].first=b[x][y].first+a[x][y-1];
            b[x][y-1].second=b[x][y].second+1;
        }
        if(x<n && y >= r){
            int k =0; // кол-во витрин снизу
            for(int t = y-r+1;t <= y;t++){
                k+=a[x+1][t];
            }
            if(b[x][y].first+k<b[x+1][y].first||(b[x][y].first+k==b[x+1][y].first&&b[x][y].second+1<b[x-1][y].second)||b[x+1][y].first==-1){
                b[x+1][y].first=b[x][y].first+k;
                b[x+1][y].second=b[x][y].second+1;
                q.push({x+1,y});
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<b[1][m].first<<"\n";
    b[1][m].first=-1;
    vector<char>c;
    int tx=1,ty=m;
    // восстановление ответа
    while(tx!=n||ty!=r){
        int tx2=tx,ty2=ty;
        if(b[tx+1][ty].first!=-1 && (b[tx2][ty2].first > b[tx+1][ty].first||b[tx2][ty2].first==-1||(b[tx2][ty2].first == b[tx+1][ty].first && b[tx2][ty2].second > b[tx+1][ty].second))){
            tx2=tx+1;ty2=ty;
        }
        if(b[tx-1][ty].first!=-1 && (b[tx2][ty2].first > b[tx-1][ty].first||b[tx2][ty2].first==-1||(b[tx2][ty2].first == b[tx-1][ty].first && b[tx2][ty2].second > b[tx-1][ty].second))){
            tx2=tx-1;ty2=ty;
        }
        if(b[tx][ty+1].first!=-1 && (b[tx2][ty2].first > b[tx][ty+1].first||b[tx2][ty2].first==-1||(b[tx2][ty2].first == b[tx][ty+1].first && b[tx2][ty2].second > b[tx][ty+1].second))){
            tx2=tx;ty2=ty+1;
        }
        if(b[tx][ty-1].first!=-1 && (b[tx2][ty2].first > b[tx][ty-1].first||b[tx2][ty2].first==-1||(b[tx2][ty2].first == b[tx][ty-1].first && b[tx2][ty2].second > b[tx][ty-1].second))){
            tx2=tx;ty2=ty-1;
        }
        if(tx2==tx+1)c.push_back('U');
        else if(tx2==tx-1)c.push_back('D');
        else if(ty2==ty+1)c.push_back('L');
        else if(ty2==ty-1)c.push_back('R');
        tx=tx2;ty=ty2;
        b[tx][ty].first=-1;
    }
    for(int i = c.size()-1;i>=0;i--)cout<<c[i];
    return 0;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это сложная задача. Вам нужен алгоритм Дейкстры. В качестве веса ребра должны быть пары `(число удаляемых витрин, 1)`. Вершина графа: `(x, y, число удалённых витрин)`. Граф в явном виде создавать не надо - он займёт много памяти. Нужна функция `neighbours` которая по текущей вершине вернёт её четыре (максимум) соседа. В таком виде это типичная задача, но времени на программирование уйдёт много.

Comment: Спасибо теперь буду учить дейкстру). Я просто думал что c помощью BFS надо

Comment: Можете сказать поч мой алгоритм неправильный?

Comment: Я вам не помогу. Код большой, из объяснений я не понял что именно вы делаете.